# What does it mean if a Pokémon has become friendly to me?

Tags: pokemon-battle-trozei

After finishing a stage, I got informed that the helper Pokémon I have been using lately is now friendly to me. What does that mean? Do I get any benefits?

Answer (score 1):

So here the altered answer, sorry I overread your tag below :/

I don't own this game by myself, but friendly pokémon are WAY stronger than unfriendly ones.
To make a pokémon friendly just keep playing with them.

> - later in the game you can use Support Pokémon
> - use them over and over to make the more friendly towards you
> - this makes attacks slightly stronger and they will be more likely to appear at the later parts of a stage"

([source](http://www.gonintendo.com/s/223838-pokemon-battle-trozei-full-gameplay-details))

As I don't own this game, I may just send you this second source:

> "Friendly Pokemon are stronger than unfriendly ones. In another topic,
>   someone said that a 1-star friendly Pokemon was equal in strength to a
>   5-star unfriendly."

([source2](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/763168-pokemon-battle-trozei/68846722))

I hope this just became useful :D

Comment: I am playing Pokemon Battle trozei, so I am not sure any of this applies.

Comment: I'll edit my answer, just give me a second :D

Comment: please comment, why you gave a "-1" ...